# roles.forEach not a function

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So basically what is happening, is this code is running when a command is run. If the user's string (UserID) fits into the array, it responds as true and sets the access level to 6. If that is false, it checks for roles and sets the access level if they have certain roles by the role names. However, the role names part is not working. For example, a user with the Moderator role (normally access level 3 / perms.three), is showing up as access level 0 and I cannot figure out why.

The way this is supposed to work is that it checks the ID of a user. If that ID is in a pre-defined array located in a .json file, it overrides all other access levels by giving an access level of 6. If the array doesn't exist it moves onto the roles function and searches to see if the role exists in the persons list of roles.

This is what I use to check the roles/userID.

```
if (command.accessLevel > perms.getAccess(message.member.roles) || command.accessLevel > perms.getAccess(message.member.id)){
      return message.channel.send("``Error: Access Denied.``");
    }
```

This is the permissions.js file:

```
const bot = require('./bot').skynet;
const config = require('./config.json');
const perms = require('./permissions.json').access;

function arrayHas(arr, val){
    var result = false;

    for (var item in arr){
        if (arr[item] == val){
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function getAccess(user){
    var access = 0;

    if (typeof(user) == 'string'){
        if (arrayHas(perms.six, user)){
            return 6;
        }
    }

    var roles = user;
    roles.forEach(function(role){
        if (arrayHas(perms.five, role.name)){
            access = 5;
            return;
        }
        else if (arrayHas(perms.four, role.name)){
            access = 4;
            return;
        }
        else if (arrayHas(perms.three, role.name)){
            access = 3;
            return;
        }
        else if (arrayHas(perms.two, role.name)){
            access = 2;
            return;
        }
        else if (arrayHas(perms.one, role.name)){
            access = 1;
            return;
        }
    });

    return access;
}

bot.on('message', message => {
    console.log(getAccess(message.member.id));
    console.log(getAccess(message.member.roles));
})

module.exports = {
    arrayHas: arrayHas,
    getAccess: getAccess,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first `if` statement, you should return a value after the inside `if` statement.  Otherwise, you'll continue to the following code `roles.forEach` for a string which will fail (`roles.forEach is not a function`)

Or place the non-string logic inside an `else` statement:

```
function getAccess(user){
    var access = 0;

    if (typeof(user) == 'string'){
        if (arrayHas(perms.six, user)){
            return 6;
        }
    } else {

        var roles = user;

        roles.forEach(function(role){
            if (arrayHas(perms.five, role.name)){
                access = 5;
                return;
            }
            else if (arrayHas(perms.four, role.name)){
                access = 4;
                return;
            }
            else if (arrayHas(perms.three, role.name)){
                access = 3;
                return;
            }
            else if (arrayHas(perms.two, role.name)){
                access = 2;
                return;
            }
            else if (arrayHas(perms.one, role.name)){
                access = 1;
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    return access;
}
```

Comment: Still got that it's not a function

Comment: It works with the userID now, but does the function error when someone with a role does it.

Comment: It shouldn't, but you'll have to test this yourself.

Comment: I just tested it and the roles bit isn't working now. Returns that it's not a function.

Comment: Can you please post the result of a `console.log` for `message.member.roles`?

Comment: I fixed it by doing
```
}else if (typeof(user) == 'object'){
```
instead of a plain else

Comment: Nevermind it's still not running the roles bit. Access for people who have the role is still set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `getAccess()`, you're setting the `access` variable but never actually returning the value. Try this revised version.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { skynet: bot } = require('./bot');
const config = require('./config.json');
const { access: perms } = require('./permissions.json');

/**
 * Return the access level of a member.
 * @param {Discord.GuildMember} member
*/
function getAccess(member) {
  if (!(member instanceof Discord.GuildMember)) return new TypeError('Expected a GuildMember.');

  if (arrayHas(perms.six, member.user.id)) return 6;

  const roles = member.roles;

  for (const role of roles) {
    if (arrayHas(perms.five, role.name)) return 5;
    if (arrayHas(perms.four, role.name)) return 4;
    if (arrayHas(perms.three, role.name)) return 3;
    if (arrayHas(perms.two, role.name)) return 2;
    if (arrayHas(perms.one, role.name)) return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```